# Browsers saying "Your connection is not private" after I reassigned a hostname to my site

Tags: dns

I had a site **www.mywebsite.com** hosted in Azure and with an SSL certificate configured and everything. When I unassigned **www.mywebsite.com** from **HOSTNAMES ASSIGNED TO SITE** in Azure and then reassigned later in the day, all my browsers started saying

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   www.mywebsite.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

whenever I went to the site.

Any idea on how to resolve?

Answer (score -1):

> Its DNS Configuration Try to set your DNS Manually using 8.8.8.8 and
>   8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers.  Have Fun :)

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive? I'll chose as best answer.